# NSFetchedResultsController: exception when object moves from higher index to lower index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table view managed by a NSFetchedResultsController. I am using the Apple-provided boilerplate code in my TableViewController. My predicate retrieves objects based on their name. Everything seems to work fine when it comes to adding/deleting objects using the 'edit' button. If I programmatically change an object's name, things also work fine **unless** the name change results in the object moving up the table, in which case I get this error:

> Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  *** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] with userInfo (null)

Say I have three objects named A, C and D. If I rename D to B then the app crashes. If I rename C to B, everything is cool.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Use of Deusty's [`SafeFetchedResultsController`](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2010/02/hideous-bug-in-nsfetchedresultscontroll.html) subclass of `NSFetchedResultsController` can help deal with tricky row update and move operations that trip up Apple's class, causing these exceptions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have helped :( but thanks for the suggestion. I have decided to simply reload the tableView whenever content changes (I never have more than 7 or 8 rows anyway...)

Comment: `SafeFetchedResultsController` does fix a lot of issues, but not all unfortunately. Changing to use `reloadData` instead of the animations seem to fix most everything though.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the exception originated in your code, and that you called `objectAtIndex:` with an invalid index. It looks like you are removing the object from your array, then trying to retrieve it before inserting it back into the array.